# Enviando arquivo para API com Autorização .Net 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Em meu sistema, preciso enviar um arquivo recebido de um formulário para uma API que salvará no Azure. Para este envio preciso passar um Bearer Token, a parte do token consegui fazer e recebe-lo, testando pelo Postman consigo enviar e receber a url que foi gerado no upload do arquivo.
No meu projeto .Net, não consigo enviar o arquivo e receber sua url para gravar no banco de dados.
Preciso passar este Token que gerei em outra classe e fazer o envio do arquivo utilizando a URL da API.
Vou colocar o código que escrevi até agora.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAzure([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    var Token = await _tokenAzure.ReturnToken();
    var _urlApi = "https://mysite.dev/api/file/savepdf";
    var _tokenApi = Token.AccessToken;

    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");

    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

    // Pass the handler to httpclient(from you are calling api)
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

    byte[] data;
    using (var br = new BinaryReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        data = br.ReadBytes((int)file.OpenReadStream().Length);
    ByteArrayContent bytes = new(data);
    MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new()
    {
        { bytes, "file", file.FileName }
    };

    var result = client.PostAsync(_urlApi, multiContent).Result;



    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Falta passar o token na requisição.

Comment: E como devo passar o Token para API?

Comment: Da forma que faz no Postman, como um header da requisição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta passar o token pra requisição.

Como o cliente HTTP tá sendo usado só dentro deste método, você pode fazer assim:

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization 
    = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token);
```

Ma também é possível fazer direto na instância de `MultipartFormDataContent`.

```cs
multiContent.Headers.Add(new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _token));
```

Note que o primeiro parâmetro (`"Bearer"`) é só um exemplo, você precisa colocar o nome do header igual faz no postman.

Veja mais sobre como fazer requisições HTTP [neste post da documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Normalmente não é um boa ideia instanciar um `HttpClient` cada vez que for usar, este post pode te ajudar a entender os motivos e como fazer da melhor forma.

Comment: Com o exemplo que deu já consegui o status de sucesso, porém ainda estou precisando receber a URL para gravar no banco, saberia com as informações que passei me explicar so como obter o retorno dessa URL que foi gerado no Azure?

Comment: @João Aí teria que abrir  outra pergunta, isso não faz parte do escopo dessa. Até porque você deve passar outras informações pra alguém poder ter ajudar com essa questão nova.